# from the pgf Basic Layer to the pgf System Layer

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to translate a code from the pgf Basic Layer to the pgf System Layer.
My first code is :

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}     
\begin{document} 

a\fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgftransformscale{.025}% 
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{71.43 bp}{238.86bp}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{310.29bp}{238.86bp}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{310.29bp}{332.57bp}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{428.57bp}{214.29bp}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{310.29bp}{96.00 bp}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{310.29bp}{189.71bp}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{71.43 bp}{189.71bp}}
\pgfpathclose 
\pgfusepath{fill,stroke}%   
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{453.14bp}{381.71bp}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{500.00bp}{381.71bp}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{500.00bp}{46.86 bp}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{453.14bp}{46.86 bp}}
\pgfpathclose 
\pgfusepath{fill,stroke}%   
\end{tikzpicture}}b  
\end{document}
```

I get what I want :[image]

Now with the pgf System Layer, I have the next code but I don't know how to add a bounding box

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}     
\begin{document} 

\makeatletter 

a\fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfsys@transformxyscale{.025}{.025}
\pgfsys@fill 
\pgfsys@moveto{71.43bp}{238.86bp}
\pgfsys@lineto{310.29bp}{238.86bp}
\pgfsys@lineto{310.29bp}{332.57bp}
\pgfsys@lineto{428.57bp}{214.29bp}
\pgfsys@lineto{310.29bp}{96.00bp}
\pgfsys@lineto{310.29bp}{189.71bp}
\pgfsys@lineto{71.43bp}{189.71bp} 
\pgfsys@closepath
\pgfsys@fillstroke
\pgfsys@fill 
\pgfsys@moveto{453.14bp}{381.71bp}
\pgfsys@lineto{500.00bp}{381.71bp}
\pgfsys@lineto{500.00bp}{46.86bp}
\pgfsys@lineto{453.14bp}{46.86bp}
\pgfsys@closepath
\pgfsys@fillstroke    
\end{tikzpicture}}b 

\end{document}
```

and unhappily the result is [image]

How to obtain the same result?

Comment: Why are you using a `tikzpicture` with PGF code and not a `pgfpicture`?

Comment: Looking at the definition of `\pgflineto` I see a `\pgf@protocolsizes` which I guess records the point so that the bounding box is updated.

Comment: In my first attempt, I used `pgfpicture` but finally I did not see differences with `tikzpicture` and I need to use this code inside a greater project. Thanks for `\pgf@protocolsizes`, because around this macro in the pgfmanual, I saw `\pgf@picmaxx` etc.  I have 90 objects and I need 20,000 lines to define these objects. I know the size of each object, also  a good solution is perhaps to set manually the bounding box. In this case, the problem now is to update the bounding box with the `scale`

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be the unequivalence of the commands

```
\pgfsys@transformxyscale{0.025}{0.025}
```

and

```
\pgftransformscale{.025}
```

The latter command is actually, as you nicely demonstrated, in the basic layer and does not act on the canvas itself. However if I make it a system layer transformation such that it applies to everything, I get precisely the bad drawing. Here is what I did:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}     
\begin{document} 

a\fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgflowlevel{\pgftransformscale{.025}}% 
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{71.43 bp}{238.86bp}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{310.29bp}{238.86bp}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{310.29bp}{332.57bp}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{428.57bp}{214.29bp}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{310.29bp}{96.00 bp}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{310.29bp}{189.71bp}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{71.43 bp}{189.71bp}}
\pgfpathclose 
\pgfusepath{fill,stroke}%   
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{453.14bp}{381.71bp}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{500.00bp}{381.71bp}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{500.00bp}{46.86 bp}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{453.14bp}{46.86 bp}}
\pgfpathclose 
\pgfusepath{fill,stroke}%   
\end{tikzpicture}}b  
\makeatletter 

\end{document}
```

and this gives

[image]

Therefore, we need to find the actual low-level equivalent of `\pgftransformscale{}` command. I have tried to find a direct handle but it seems that  relative coordinate transformations are not so straightforward to be handled at the system layer. I can see that the unit vectors are `\edef`ed in `pgfcoretransformation.code.tex` file so I don't have  much hope (but my knowledge is with what is documented, I might be wrong about this).